# Cleaning up messy URL's

Tags: php, apache, url, mod-rewrite

Lets say we have a URL that looks like this: http://www.onegreatwebadress.com/index.php?sideID=home
and we want it to show something like this instead: http://www.onegreatwebadress.com/home

How is it done with mod_rewrite  -> apache 2.2?

Here is my .htaccess (placed in the root file of the webserver) :
Additionaly, the website im working in is placed in a sub dir: www\onegreatsite

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /onegreatwwebadress/ 
RewriteRule ^sideID([a-zA-Z0-9]+).php$ sideID.php?=$1

Comment: Which previous example?  Can you show us what you are doing?  It's very hard to simply guess why it's not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by uploading a file called:
`.htaccess` to your web directory. Apache will read this, and will allow you to manipulate your URL, amongst other things.

A website I have found useful for performing actions and also informative for new users:

http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

Examples published on this page will help solve your situation.

Comment: yeh, that is exactly how I do it. But for some reason it wont work, I guess I just have to keep trying.

Comment: Then can you display the contents of your `.htaccess`

Comment: Update it in your question with correct formatting

Comment: Oh, ofc.. pardon me. Here we go ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your .htaccess is not functioning properly. This could be fixed by changing the Apache configuration. Often these kind of .htaccess problems can be fixed by adding `AllowOverride all` to the `<Directory>` section in the Apache configuration file. Here is an example.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
   AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

This will allow the .htaccess file to override any previous stated configurations.